# Android: saving application state when going to the "background"

Tags: android, android-activity, persistence, state

I have a complex Android app with a decent amount of application state that needs to be persisted (in a specific format). Writing out the data is not an instantaneous operation and so it would be ideal to minimize persisting it unnecessarily.

Because of the persistence overhead it is not practical to persist the state every time it is changed. Ideally, persisting state would be triggered when the app is "backgrounded" by the user tapping the 'home' button or tapping the 'back' button on the app's root Activity (or by an incoming call, etc.). This minimizes persistence overhead while maintaining state consistency from the user's perspective. The question is how can you detect if the app is being "backgrounded"?

The Activity lifecycle calls (onStart, onResume, onPause and friends) don't help as the app has many different activities, any one of which could be active when the user taps 'home'. Furthermore, the calls get called when Activities get pushed, popped (and bottom killed) on the Activity stack and so they don't reflect if the app is going away or not.

So how does an app detect when it is going to the background?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to persist some state when any of your activities goes to the background you could always extend Activity, add two abstact methods which you call in onPause and onResume.  Then each one of your Activities which extends this new abstract class would be forced to define saveState() and loadState(). These methods could define what to save and load for each activity.

That is just an example of using inheritance to force your programmers to implement otherwise overlooked methods and techniques methods.  You can just tell your programmers, if you ever need to save the state of an activity just extend this type of activity and then the IDE will put them on the path of your design.

```
package com.yourcompany.yourpackage;

import android.app.Activity;

public abstract class ActivitySaveState extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadState();
    }


    public abstract void loadState();
    public abstract void saveState();



}
```

Also you could instantiate some of the state saving mechanisms for them in the super class (i.e. web service endpoint, DAO or w/e your persistence unit maybe.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        saveState();

        CustomDataAccessObject dao = new CustomDataAccessObject("Activity3");

        loadState(dao );
    }


    public abstract void loadState(CustomDataAccessObject dao);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I got in Android there is no concept of *application going to background* as a whole. Your *application* is thought of in terms of a *federation of activities/services/...* working together. And potentially you could configure it so that it can start from different activities, in different processes, in different tasks, so it's (almost?) impossible to figure out when your application goes to background.

Apart from this, to your question:

MyXxxActivity.onPause is the last safe chance you have to trigger the saving of data that has to be persisted across different "runs" of your application. This is not *transient* application state, instead it's stuff that goes to DB/File System storage and that you want to retrieve again in the next run.

I assume the application state you mention falls into this category.

So your saving must be triggered from each activity's onPause. If there's any state shared across different activities (e.g. in the Application), it should be *collected* from each onPause. Or its saving should be triggered as well from each onPause.

If the saving operation takes time, you should not run it on the main (UI) thread. Instead you should hand it off to another thread. Again, assuming this is *important* state that you *do* want to be persisted, then it's best to hand this work to a Service (as opposed to an AsyncTask e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

`The Activity lifecycle calls (onStart, onResume, onPause and friends) don't help as the app has many different activities`

Your activities should be independent enough that you shouldn't need to know when your entire application is in the background. It sounds like you have other design issues that we can't help you with without more specifics.

Comment: The structure of the activities is not relevant. I have a piece of state that is expensive to serialize - a constraint. To minimize the expense while keeping the user experience consistent the ideal place to save the state seems to be when the user "takes his eye off the app". I'm looking for an answer to that question, if it can't be done, then so be it; At least I'll know it can't be done and I can stop searching for a way.

Comment: @acoward: The structure of the activities is very relevant because that's the point of having separate activities. How are you transferring this expensive state between activities anyway? It's not that this isn't possible, it's just that there are much better ways of doing whatever it is your end goal is. And instead of just answering your question, we're trying to help solve your problem.

Comment: advices that end "you have design issues" just hide the fact that the API DOESN'T have the simple call "your app is going to background", just like iOS has....

Comment: @Danail: Thanks for that extremely relevant and useful comment. It does a lot to further this discussion. You are clearly superior for recognising that android's API doesn't match the iphone's.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest managing your data on an activity-by-activity basis.  This is suggested in the android docs.

For any activity that alters your persistent state, save that state when leaving the activity.

---

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

onPause() is where you deal with the user leaving your activity. Most importantly, any changes made by the user should at this point be committed (usually to the ContentProvider holding the data).

Answer (score -1):

This thread is pretty old, just to say onSaveInstanceState of activity is triggered when app is on background or when the user press home button on device. So there, you can save state, on load it on onrestore and so on...